# How to optimize SELECT query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that houses all of the logs of the system. It houses the insertion and update logs of an item. My query checks the latest updates based on the last time the system checked for updates.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT LCINDIV.CLIENTID, LCINDIV.COID, BIRTHDAY, NATIONAL, ACRNO, CIVSTAT, GENDER, RELIGION, SSSID, TIN, RESCERT, EDUCLV, DEGREE, RESIDENT, LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, DTPLRES, NATIONLT, LCINDIV.SERVERUPDATE
FROM LCINDIV
LEFT OUTER JOIN LCCLIENT
    ON LCCLIENT.CLIENTID = LCINDIV.CLIENTID
WHERE
   AUDITKY IN (SELECT AUDITKY FROM LSAUDIT WHERE ENTRYDT > '04-Nov-2019' AND ENTRYTM > '15:15:10')
```

Here is what my query does it will get the client information if the AUDITKY is in the AUDITKY of the table LSAUDIT WHERE the ENTRYDT is greater than the current date and ENTRYTM is greater than the current time.

My problem is when I execute this query it takes about 30-60 seconds to execute. Is there a way for me to improve my SQL Query?

Table Specs:
LCCLIENT - 5,000+ rows
LCINDIV - 5,000+ rows
LSUDIT - 5,000,000+ rows

Table Structure:

> LSAUDIT Table
>  AUDITNO CHAR
>  AUDITTP CHAR
> AUDITKY CHAR
> ENTRYBY CHAR
> ENTRYDT DATE
> ENTRYTM CHAR

Comment: And what table is audit key in?  What are the data types of the date and time columns?

Comment: in LCCLIENT and LSAUDIT table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for `EXISTS`.  Note that your `LEFT JOIN` is really an `INNER JOIN`, so:

```
SELECT LCINDIV.CLIENTID, LCINDIV.COID, BIRTHDAY, NATIONAL, ACRNO,
       CIVSTAT, GENDER, RELIGION, SSSID, TIN, RESCERT, EDUCLV,
       DEGREE, RESIDENT, LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, DTPLRES, NATIONLT,
       LCINDIV.SERVERUPDATE
FROM LCINDIV JOIN
     LCCLIENT
     ON LCCLIENT.CLIENTID = LCINDIV.CLIENTID
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM LSAUDIT
              WHERE LSAUDIT.AUDITKY = LCCLIENT.AUDITKEY AND
                    (LSAUDIT.ENTRYDT > TRUNC(SYSDATE) OR
                     LSAUDIT.ENTRYDT = TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND LSAUDIT.ENTRYTM > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS')
                    )
              );
```

For performance, an index on `LSAUDIT(AUDITKY, ENTRYDT, ENTRYTM)` is helpful.

Comment: perhaps it would be `SYSDATE` :) @Blank317

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 suggestions.

> 1. to use exists instead of IN
> 2. combine your date and time

```
SELECT LCINDIV.CLIENTID
    , LCINDIV.COID, BIRTHDAY
    , NATIONAL, ACRNO, CIVSTAT, GENDER, RELIGION, SSSID, TIN, RESCERT
    , EDUCLV, DEGREE, RESIDENT, LNAME, FNAME, MNAME, DTPLRES, NATIONLT, LCINDIV.SERVERUPDATE
FROM LCINDIV
LEFT OUTER JOIN LCCLIENT
    ON LCCLIENT.CLIENTID = LCINDIV.CLIENTID
WHERE
   EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM LSAUDIT WHERE
     to_date(ENTRYDT||ENTRYTM, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') > to_date('04-Nov-2019'||'15:15:10', 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))
```

Comment: there is an error in the query "Hour must be between 0 to 23"

Comment: @Blank317, seems you have data issue. tried your sample date and time seems good. see sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c0be1c/30823/0

Comment: I am using Oracle 9i is that ok?

Comment: it should, to_date existed in oracle in later vesions

Comment: Is there a way to eliminate time that exceeds 24 and below 0?

Comment: I think you need to fix your dates, if you can share the problematic date, maybe we can help

Comment: There are 5 million data how can I check what date is the problem?

Comment: Concatenation and applying `to_date` for `WHERE` condition within the subquery would make ineffective an index on `ENTRYDT` column if exists any.